# How to partly clean command promt

Tags: python-3.x, cmd

I'm creating a small game in python where two players choose 1 of 3 characters and fight each other by turns. So when I launch game in cmd, there are some info that I want to refresh on cmd every turn so I use "import os" and "os.system('cls')". This cleans whole window. The thing is I want some information to stay on screen, like how much one's character done damage on last rounds etc. Is it possible at all?

Or maybe its possible to do that when I open my program, two cmd screens opens, both store different information and communicate with each other?

Comment: You might want to Google for ANSI control commands or tui libraries

Answer (score 0):

ANSI escape codes are your friend. Among other things, it allows you to move the cursor around the screen. For example

```py
print('\e[2A\e[3C')
```

will move the cursor two spaces up and three to the right. [This wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) gives a good synopsis, see the section on CSI sequences. These codes work on most Unix/Linux OSs and newer versions of Windows 10.